# MySql Join table that doesn't have any matches shows null values

Tags: mysql, join

Hi I'm trying to join a table like so:

```
  SELECT
    u.mobile_number,
    u.dob,
    u.gender,
    u.country,
    SUM(b.reward_points) AS points
  FROM users u
  JOIN bookings b ON u.user_id=b.user_id
  WHERE u.user_id=20
  AND b.attended=1
  AND b.review_completed=1
  AND b.date > "2010-03-12"
  AND b.reward_used=0
```

however because the bookings table has no records for user_id 20, all the columns returned have NULL value. I want to get the values for the user back and points returned NULL (when no corresponding rows are found in the bookings table). How can I make this work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect something like a full join will do it but that is not available in MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move all conditions on table b from the WHERE clause to the ON clause:

```
  SELECT
    u.mobile_number,
    u.dob,
    u.gender,
    u.country,
    SUM(b.reward_points) AS points
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN bookings b 
    ON u.user_id=b.user_id
    AND b.attended=1
    AND b.review_completed=1
    AND b.date > "2010-03-12"
    AND b.reward_used=0
  WHERE u.user_id=20
```

**Explanation**:
The `WHERE` clause filters the result, no matter what type of `JOIN` you use - records with no match in table b can't satisfy any condition on this table so they are not returned by the query. The `ON` clause defines how to attach records from table b to records from table u (so only records with b.attended=1 and so on are joined).

Comment: YES!! Thank you, I should have known that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `INNER JOIN`, instead of a `JOIN`, to only join if there are rows in the `booking` table that answer the condition `u.user_id=b.user_id`.

Comment: When I remove the SUM out and using an INNER join then I get a results set of 0 rows. If I then remove all the AND clauses dealing with the bookings table then I still get 0 rows. If I then change the join to LEFT OUTER then I get the user details, but if I add back the AND clauses I get 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the clause:

```
group by u.mobile_number, u.dob, u.gender, u.country
```

at the end of your original queryand also use the INNER JOIN instead of JOIN. Hope this helps.